# Trying to retrieve an mp3 file stored in AWS S3 and load it into my React client as a Blob...it's not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a react web app that allows users to record mp3 files in the browser. These mp3 files are saved in an AWS S3 bucket and can be retrieved and loaded back into the react app during the user's next session.

Saving the file works just fine, but when I try to retrieve the file with getObject() and try to create an mp3 blob on the client-side, I get a small, unusable blob:

[image]

Here's the journey the recorded mp3 file goes on:

**1) Saving to S3**

In my Express/Node server, I receive the uploaded mp3 file and save to the S3 bucket:

```
//SAVE THE COMPLETED AUDIO TO S3
router.post("/", [auth, upload.array('audio', 12)], async (req, res) => {

    try {
        //get file
        const audioFile = req.files[0];

        //create object key
        const userId = req.user;
        const projectId = req.cookies.currentProject;
        const { sectionId } = req.body;
        const key = `${userId}/${projectId}/${sectionId}.mp3`;

        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(audioFile.path)

        const uploadParams = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Body: fileStream,
            Key: key,
            ContentType: "audio/mp3" 
        }

        const result = await s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
        
        res.send(result.key);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send();
    }
});
```

As far as I know, there are no problems at this stage. The file ends up in my S3 bucket with "type: mp3" and "Content-Type: audio/mp3".

**2) Loading file from S3 Bucket**

When the react app is loaded up, an HTTP GET Request is made in my Express/Node server to retrieve the mp3 file from the S3 Bucket

```
//LOAD A FILE FROM S3
router.get("/:sectionId", auth, async(req, res) => {    

    try {
        //create key from user/project/section IDs
        const sectionId = req.params.sectionId;
        const userId = req.user;
        const projectId = req.cookies.currentProject;
        const key = `${userId}/${projectId}/${sectionId}.mp3`;

        const downloadParams = {
            Key: key,
            Bucket: bucketName
        }

        s3.getObject(downloadParams, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                res.status(500).send();
            }
            res.send(data);
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send();
    }
    
});
```

The "data" returned here is as such:
[image]

**3) Making a Blob URL on the client**

Finally, in the React client, I try to create an 'audio/mp3' blob from the returned array buffer

```
const loadAudio = async () => {
        
        const res = await api.loadAudio(activeSection.sectionId);
        
        const blob = new Blob([res.data.Body], {type: 'audio/mp3' });
        
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                
        globalDispatch({ type: "setFullAudioURL", payload: url });
}
```

The created blob is severely undersized and appears to be completely unusable. Downloading the file results in a 'Failed - No file' error.
[image]

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now with no luck. I would seriously appreciate any advice you can give!

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

Just some additional info here: in the upload parameters, I set the Content-Type as audio/mp3 explicitly. This is because when not set, the Content-Type defaults to 'application/octet-stream'. Either way, I encounter the same issue with the same result.

**EDIT 2**
At the request of a commenter, here is the res.data available on the client-side after the call is complete:

[image]

Comment: Can you log the `res.data`?

Comment: Hi @jellycsc, thanks for the response! I just added in the response

Comment: 1. use curl to download from S3 bucket and then play that mp3 just to verify that the result of the S3.PUT op is OK on mimeType etc . 
2. code a minimal audio tag in ( jsfiddl, jsbin ... ) to verify that html tag loads and plays from S3
<audio controls="" type="audio/mpeg" src="$S3.bucket_ID"></audio>

then go on with JS ops  FETCH and GET_blob from the url

Comment: @RobertRowntree thanks for the comment. I just tried two things based on your advice - I downloaded the mp3 directly from the S3 bucket, verifying that it works correctly. I then tried to play the mp3 file using the object URL in an audio tag in JSFiddle and that worked too. The issue has to be with how I'm pulling the file back into my react app

Comment: have u tried a simple 'audio' tag in the html with attrs set correctly as in :   audio.setAttribute('type', 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;');
  audio.setAttribute('src', url.audio );  just give it the the public url of the bucket item . If you set priviledge accordingly on S3 the audio control will take care of the fetch from S3 and u dont need any of the explicit blob code for create url etc

Comment: Hi @RobertRowntree, I still need to somehow create a blob from that url to be able to have the user edit that mp3 file and pick up where they left off in the editing process, correct? I'm not just looking to play the file. Let me know if I'm understanding your advice correctly

Comment: then, b4 you attach the editor ( see webaudio context and filtering ) you can fetch from the S3 url using as example : https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/147 . be aware of syntactic diffs among arrayBuffer and node buffer for the binary . IMO fetch -> buffer -> webAudio.context where you apply your filtering may help you sketch out transit protocol with obj.type w mime-type and a suitable JS type on which to perform edits that u require

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the output of `res.data` on the client, there are a couple of things that you'd need to do:

- Replace uses of `res.data.Body` with `res.data.Body.data` (as the actual data array is in the `data` attribute of `res.data.Body`)
- Pass a `Uint8Array` to the `Blob` constructor, as the existing array is of a larger type, which will create an invalid blob

Putting that together, you would end up replacing:

```
const blob = new Blob([res.data.Body], {type: 'audio/mp3' });
```

with:

```
const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(res.data.Body.data)], {type: 'audio/mp3' });
```

Having said all that, the underlying issue is that the NodeJS server is sending the content over as a JSON encoded serialisation of the response from S3, which is likely overkill for what you are doing. Instead, you can send the `Buffer` across directly, which would involve, on the server side, replacing:

```
res.send(data);
```

with:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'audio/mp3');
res.send(data.Body);
```

and on the client side (likely in the `loadAudio` method) processing the response as a blob instead of JSON. If using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) then it could be as simple as:

```
const blob = await fetch(<URL>).then(x => x.blob());
```

Comment: Hi @msbit, I have yet to try this solution but this is exactly the type of answer + level of detail I was looking for. For that, I'd like to award you the bounty for this question as a thank you! Once I try this solution out tonight, I'll comment for more help if needed or mark the answer as correct.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. Marking this answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

Your server side code seems alright to me. I'm not super clear about the client-side approach. Do you load this into the blob into the HTML5 Audio player.

I have a few approaches, assuming you're trying to load this into an audio tag in the UI.

```html
<audio controls src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,blahblahblah or html src" />
```

Assuming that the file you had uploaded to S3 is valid here are two approaches:

1. Return the data as a `base64` string instead of as a buffer directly from S3. You can do this in your server side by returning as

```
 const base64MP3 = data.Body.toString('base64');
```

You can then pass this in to the MP3 player in the `src` property and it will play the audio. Prefix it with `data:audio/mpeg;base64`

2. Instead of returning the entire MP3 file, have your `sectionID` method return a `presigned` S3 URL. Essentially, this is a direct link to the object in S3 that is authorized for say 5 minutes.

Then you should be able to use this URL directly to stream the audio
and set it as the src. Keep in mind that it will expire.

```js
 const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
        Bucket: myBucket,
        Key: myKey,
        Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You stated: ***"The created blob is severely undersized and appears to be completely unusable"***

This appears to me that you have an encoding issue. Once you read the MP3 from the Amazon S3 bucket, you need to encode it properly so it functions in a web page.

I did a similar multimedia use case that involved MP4 and a Java app. That is, i wanted a MP4 obtained from a bucket to play in the web page - as shown in this example web app.

[image]

Once I read the byte stream from the S3 bucket, I had to encode it so it would play in a HTML Video tag. Here is a good reference to [properly encode a MP3 file](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/javascript-tutorial-record-audio-and-encode-it-to-mp3-2eedcd466e78).

Comment: Hi @smac2020, thank you for the comment. I just read the attached article and I'm still quite confused on how to go about taking what is returned to me from S3 (an array buffer) and then create an audio blob, not an mp3 file. I may not be understanding correctly. Are you able to provide more step-by-step detail?